# AFNetworking 2 with AFSSLPinningModeCertificate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, https, afnetworking-2

I have problem with SSL pinning. First question: is it OK if I logged in via Safari, added required certificate to keychain, then exported file from Keychain app and put it in my Xcode project? I have .cer file already so few questions here on SO seemed to be irrelevant for my situation.

Here is my code:

```
- (AFSecurityPolicy*) customSecurityPolicy{
  NSString *cerPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cert_name" ofType:@"cer"];
  NSData *certData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cerPath];
  AFSecurityPolicy *securityPolicy = [[AFSecurityPolicy alloc] init];
  [securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:NO];
  [securityPolicy setPinnedCertificates:@[certData]];
  [securityPolicy setSSLPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
  return securityPolicy;
}

-(void)secureLogin{    
  NSString *server = @"https_url";
  NSDictionary *params = @{@"login": self.loginField.text, @"password" : self.passField.text};
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSString *JSON = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                                                options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                                                  error:&error]
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  //NSLog(@"JSON: %@", JSON);

  AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
  [manager setSecurityPolicy:[self customSecurityPolicy]];
  manager.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
  manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
  [manager POST:server
     parameters:@{@"data" : JSON}
        success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSLog(@"hell yea! %@", responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
        }];
}
```

If I set `setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES]` then it's cool, but not secure. I'm trying to get some sense out of it, but nothing so far. I keep getting:

> error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
>   (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)" UserInfo=0x8a35800 
>   {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https_url, 
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https_url}

Comment: Have you figured this out yet? I'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: look my comment under my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you have a valid certificate issued by a public CA you should probably either include a collection of all certificates from the issued certificate up to the root certificate including all intermediate certificates or you should set the following:

```
[securityPolicy setValidatesCertificateChain:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me (at least for now) was to drag&drop my .cer file into simulator and install certificate, which made connecting via ssl successful. Not sure if this should be the proper way, I'd prefer doing that by AFNetworking, but seem to work

Comment: As per my understanding, you dragged&dropped your .cer file into simulator, and you chose to 'trust' them in your simulator. But when you issue your app to your customers, they would not have such a choice to install the certificate, unless you put your .cer in your website and ask your customers to install them manually, that not make sense.

Comment: yeah, but as I said: this was temporary and I hope to work with normal certificates etc at final stage... haven't been working on that for a long tim though

Answer (score 0):

Because your Domain name is not registered
You maybe use similar to https://42.62.101.10:80/andsoon
you need download Site certificate (.cer) in you Xcode.
and then

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.securityPolicy =  [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];
[manager.securityPolicy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];
```

// Just try

Comment: Does your answer end with “Just try”, or did you intend to paste something right after it?